# How to let IDE know a certain folder should be mapped into a certain package path?

Tags: import, ide, pycharm, python-import, pydev

I use PyCharm and Eclipse with PyDev.

To be specific, I am using Odoo and setting up project.

https://github.com/odoo/odoo

Here is the folder structure.

```
odoo-12
|-addons
| '-web
|   '-...
|-odoo
  '-addons
    '-...
```

[image]

In source code for example:
`addons/purchase/controllers/portal.py`

```
# Unresolved yet this is the official source code
from odoo.addons.web.controllers.main import Binary

# Resolved perfectly
from addons.web.controllers.main import Binary
```

I understand the reason why this one works

```
from addons.web.controllers.main import Binary
```

but how can I make this works instead?

```
from odoo.addons.web.controllers.main import Binary
```

I cannot and should not modify any Odoo source code to make IDE resolving path correctly

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse/PyDev you should be able to set your source folder to the folder containing `odoo` and it should work...

Comment: The problem is directory ./addons not and ./odious/addons working

Comment: In that case, add `odoo` itself as a source folder.

Comment: No, `./addons` is mapped wrongly, `./odoo/addons` is mapped correctly